# Can MySQL dynamicly create indexes for JSON column?

Tags: mysql, sql

Given you have a JSON column called `slug` structured like this:

```
{
    "en_US": "slug",
    "nl_NL": "nl/different-slug"
}
```

This could be indexed by adding generated columns to the table that point to the values of `en_US` and `nl_NL`. This works fine but adding a third locale would require a table schema update.

Would it be possible to let MySQL automagicly index all the key value pairs in the JSON without explicitly defining them in the schema?

Comment: How would you use those indices?

Comment: To speed up querying against a slug

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mysql manual on [json data type](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json.html) says:

> JSON columns, like columns of other binary types, are not indexed directly; instead, you can create an index on a generated column that extracts a scalar value from the JSON column. See Indexing a Generated Column to Provide a JSON Column Index, for a detailed example.

So, the answer is no, mysql cannot index the contents of a json column automatically. You need to define and index generated columns.